# Find the median of the random variable X , where density function is given

Tags: probability

Find the median of the random variable X , where density function  is given by $ f(x)=\frac{x}{32}-\frac{1}{4} $  on the interval $ [8,16] $.

**Answer:**

Let $ m $ be the median , then

$ \int_{8}^{m} f(x)=\frac{x}{32}-\frac{1}{4} =\frac{1}{2} $ gives

$ m^2-16m+96=0 $,

$ or, \ m \ \ is \ complex \ \ number $.

**So how can I find the median ? Any help?**

Comment: Keep going. Ensure your $m$ is the interval of interest.

Comment: But  m becomes complex number, which is not possible. I think it should be one of  $ \int_{0}^{m} f(x)dx=\frac{1}{2} $  or $ \int_{8}^{c} f(x)dx=\int_{m}^{16}f(x)dx $.

Comment: You need to only do $\int_8 ^m f \ dx =0.5$. Perhaps you made an arithmetic error.

Comment: Yes, but this gives $ m=8 \pm \sqrt{32} $ , how can I eliminate one value ? I think $ 8+\sqrt{32} \in [8,16] $ is the median . Is it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_8^m \frac{x}{32}-\frac14 dx = \frac12$$

$$\left[\frac{x^2}{64}-\frac{x}{4}\right]_{x=8}^{x=m}=\frac12$$

$$\frac{m^2}{64}-\frac{m}{4}-(1-2)=0.5$$

$$\frac{m^2}{64}-\frac{m}{4}+\frac12=0$$

$$m^2-16m+32=0$$

\begin{align}m&=\frac{16\pm\sqrt{16^2-4(32)}}{2} \\
&=\frac{16\pm 4\sqrt{16-4(2)}}{2} \\
&=\frac{16\pm 8\sqrt{4-(2)}}{2}\\
&=8 \pm4\sqrt{2}\end{align}

Since $m \geq 8$, $m=8+4\sqrt{2}$.

Remark about your working:

Though we end up with the same solution, our equation differs.

If the roots of a polynomials are $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Then $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=x^2-(\alpha+\beta)x + \alpha \beta$

If you find that the roots is $8 \pm \sqrt{32}$, the product of roots would be $(8 + \sqrt{32})(8 -\sqrt{32})=64 - 32=32$.

Something is weird about your equation.